# How to disable close captions(CC) on HTML5 Video Player

Tags: javascript, html, video

Is there any option to disable close captions(CC) button on page load.

[image]

Comment: is this the same as the question/answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916914/toggling-closed-caption-in-html5-video-and-disabling-default-video-controls or here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20648184/turning-off-closed-caption-on-html5-video-by-default ? (didn't want to just paste the answer here if it's a duplicate)

Comment: What page is this on?